# Visual code studio editor.tabSize after file save

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've overridden my default visual code setting to change tab size and it seems to work when hit tab but after when i save it changes to the default tab size which is 4. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Visual Code User Settings

```
{
 "editor.tabSize": 2
}
```

Visual Code Studio Version: **1.17.1** 
OS Version: Ubuntu **14.04**

Comment: This is in `settings.json`, right?

Comment: Yes. I solved the issue. It was a beautifier plugin which was overriding the tabSize on save. This was happening on my colleague's machine, So i wasn't really aware of the plugins he had in his VSC until i found the beautifier plugin. Thank you.